# SSIS Script Component cant find stored procedure

Tags: .net, ssis

I have a script component that calls a stored procedure, when I run the application, it says it cannot find the procedure.

What do I need to do to get the script component to see and run my procedure?  Thanks

Here is the I am using to call the eprocedure.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.
SqlConnection Conn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)Connections.ASMADO.AcquireConnection(null);

System.Data.SqlClient.
SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("exec InsertArptServices" , Conn);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fkObjectID", Row.fkObjectID));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@services", Row.OtherServices));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in the right database, the only other thing I can think of is to prefix with the schema name, i.e.

> exec dbo.InsertArptServices

Comment: Yeah, I tried that first but it did not work. I have been able to load tables with the normal destination components successfully but it cannot see the procedure. Puzzling.

Answer (score 3):

With `CommandType.StoredProcedure` command text should be `ProcedureName` not `exec ProcedureName`. So in your case try:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("InsertArptServices" , Conn);
```